# How to best cover one shape with another

Tags: geometry

I was asking myself a pretty simple question today, but no matter how much i try i am not able to find a satisfying answer anywhere, nor could i come up with one.

If you have two shapes e.g. an L shape and a circle. Where the thickness of the L shape is NOT negligible and we have the following rules:

The diameter of the circle is larger than the thickness of the L shape but smaller than the lenght of the L shape.
The thickness of the L shape is smaller than the length.

How to you position the circle to cover the maximum Area of the L shape, and why so ?

Comment: What is the relevant of the thickness? May be a drawing could help with understanding your question.

Comment: For any configuration that the L-shape/polygon intersect with the disc. Walk around its boundary and let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{2n}$ be those points intersecting the circle tranversely. In order for the area of intersection of L-shape/polygon and disc to be extermum (with respect to translation of L-shape/polygon). A necessary condition is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \vec{p}_k = \vec{0}$. You can use this to limit the search of the configuration which maximizes the area of intersection.